# Microsoft excel - create 2D table from list of pairs

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'd like to ask for help with following excel issue: I am interpreting results of a questionnaire so I have a pair of values. First column contains a category, let's say A,B,C, while the second has a rating 1-3. So I have data like this:

| Category | Rating |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |

you get the drift.

I'd like to count how many people for each category gave specific rating.

in this case, the expected solution would be like this:

| X | rating 1 | rating 2 | rating 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I tried going with COUNTIF, but I cannot seem to get the condition quite right.
I'd rather avoid using auxiliary cells, but if it cannot be helped, I am able to use them.

Comment: you have two criteria Category and rating, so you'll need `COUNTIFS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try Power Query.

1. Select the data range, right-click on it > Get Data from Table/Range.

[image]

2. Select the 2 columns > Transform tab > Group By, set `Advanced` and choose these 2 columns as grouping.The new column is call **Count** as default. The Operation is "Count Rows".

[image]

3.Sort the Rating column.

4. Select Count column and Rating column > Transform tab > Pivot column. Choose **Count** column as the values column.

[image]

[image]

5. Then click File > Close and Load the table to one worksheet.

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed, also thanks for introduction to the Power Query. As a note, it seems that on MacOS the PowerQuery capabilites are quite limited (or at least hidden in vastly different place). Once I booted to Windows, I was able to follow your guide to the Tee.

Answer (score 0):

Using formulas, you can use the following two:

```
=UNIQUE($A$2:$A$5)

=SUM(  ($A$2:$A$5=$J2) * ($B$2:$B$5 = VALUE( RIGHT(K$1, LEN(K$1)-6)) )  )
```

The first goes in the cell of the first column under the header, the `X`. It will `SPILL` as far as it needs.

The second goes in the rest of the cells. Place it in the next column, next to the `UNIQUE()` formula, then copy and paste into the rest of the cells.

It uses two conditions, that of that row's "X" value being the value in each row of the "Category" column in the data table, and returning an array of `TRUE/FALSE` values.

The second condition uses string building techniques to strip out the word `rating` from each column header leaving the string of its numerical content following the word and then changes its type to be the numerical value, not the string. That is then compared to each numerical value in the "Rating" column of the data table returning its own array of `TRUE/FALSE` values.

As such, those arrays are not useful. But perform an operation on them that requires them to be numerical values instead and you `coerce` Excel into changing them both to arrays of `1/0` values. Those two arrays are then multiplied returning an array the size of the number of rows in the data table with a value of `1` for any row meeting both of its cell's conditions, and `0` (1*0=0, 0*1=0, and 0*0=0) for the other three possibilities.

`SUM()` then takes that single array and sums up the individual values returning what happens to be the number of pairs in the data table that match its cell's conditions.

However, if you have a large data set, or one that changes often, the Power Query approach can solve a lot of tedious things, like that of making sure your "Rating" cell formulas fill enough rows in the output, and not too few or two many. Plenty of ways to take care of those mundane concerns, the housekeeping, but PQ will let you always match things up exactly and update in a single command to do so. It will also be happy to read the data from a file, even if that file is this one, but if your data comes from, say, a general CSV file, or, say, a PDF-form's data file, PQ will handle getting it from there for you as well. It's killer for automation and this kind of usage is absolute "a beginner and his mouse" work. Absolutely nothing special in the way of knowledge. My own first use was exactly that, reading another Excel file and massaging the data a couple steps and outputting it into a Table. Extracting info from that output using formulas in a report range was harder.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with a simple COUNTIFS otherwise:

Assuming your data table starts in A1 with headers:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5,"A",$B$2:$B$5,1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).